# Next JS : Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, next.js

I have a Next.js application that works and then when I leave it and come back to it I get

```
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\gmacr\\Google Drive\\Optical-Font-Website\\O\\.next\\server\\pages'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! opt@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opt@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gmacr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-16T21_14_26_886Z-debug.log
```

I tried using npm clean cache.  using Windows 10.  When I create a new Next app and copy my working files over the program runs without error until I leave it for a while and come back to it...

Comment: What do you mean by _"when I leave it and come back to it"_? Can you describe the specific steps you do to make the error occur?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens to me when the project directory is inside "Google Drive"!!

All you have to do is delete the "`.next"` directory.

Or add a script to package.json to delete it (windows 10 tested):

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "(if exist .next rd /s /q .next 2>nul) && next dev",
},
```

Comment: Fantastic! Moving out of Google drive worked . Just to clarify, are you saying I can keep it in the drive if I delete the .next or write the script?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeM! Yes, you can keep it in drive, as long as you manually delete the .next directory every time you start your server (that's what the script does). I keep my projects inside the drive as well, I've created a script to keep the node_modules outside (avoid large unnecessary sync) take a look: https://github.com/lobobruno/googledrive-nodemodules-ignore/blob/master/link-nodemodules.bat

Comment: Wait... Why use Drive and not GIT + Github?